# Eclipse shows source folders twice when importing Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

On a simple application, with a valid `Maven` POM file that compiles as expected (e.g., when running mvn install) and which works just fine for IntelliJ IDEA, `Eclipse` insists on displaying the source code twice.

Assuming that the top level package of the project is `com.example.app` and that the source code is placed in a path ending in `pro/java/`, the structure of the project is something like

- pro/java/main/com/example/app...
- pro/java/test/com/example/app...

After importing the `Maven` project in `Eclipse`, a nested `src` forder is created in the workspace, below which there are nested versions of the actual source folders, e.g.

- src/java/main/com/example/app
- src/java/main/com/com/example/app

In addition to that, there are 2 "valid" source folders in the workspace, i.e.

- src/main/java...
- src/test/java...

Excluding those two folders from the source path leaves nothing to be compiled and keeping the nested `src` folder causes all sorts of weird problems in compilation from within `Eclipse`.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please show me the source folders of you project? right click the project-->build path-->config build path and then click source tab.

Comment: TYhey are the two I mentioned above, i.e. src/main/java... and src/test/java...

Comment: So I think at least you should add the 2 folders you mentioned which are lost as source folder, so it could be compiled by Maven.

Comment: Which lost folders? The 2 folders I mentioned are already Eclipse source folders. Also, the code does compile in Maven, Eclipse is the problem. :-)

Comment: I mean the folder: src/java/com/example/app and src/java/main/com/com/example.app. I used eclipse with Maven to build my prjoect, I didn't see any issue yet.

Comment: I have seen the issue with other projects as well. It probably is a bug of Eclipse, when importing Maven projects.

Comment: Really? I also do the import of Maven project with eclipse and don't see and issue.

Comment: It does not happen in all cases, which makes things even more weird. Other people on the web have reported similar behavior, but my search has revealed no solution thus far.